# Scala video materials

Tags: scala

We are planning to use the Scala in our upcoming project. We are all new to this technology. Where to find the video materials for Scala to develop a web base application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the play! framework. The new 2.0 version is written in scala and supports a lot of idiomatic scala usage, including scala-based templates.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaHome

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki

http://www.scoop.it/t/playframework

Not all videos, but worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

http://typesafe.com/resources/videos is the page of the typesafe video matreial. I recommend using Lift, although I did not use it at all, it is really common.

Answer (score 0):

There are some videos on scala basics here:

- http://vimeo.com/24720874
- http://vimeo.com/25335827

and for development using the Lift you can check out this screen cast which gives a good introduction to the framework

- http://vimeo.com/18496998